# What is the meaning of service-to-service application?

Tags: service, botframework, direct-line-botframework, service-application

In a hunt to understand how [RCS](http://www.gsma.com/network2020/rcs-2/) can be used with [Bots](https://dev.botframework.com/), we were referring to [this document](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/#navtitle) and saw a term **service-to-service application** for choosing an authentication mechanism.

> Especially in reference to [bots](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/#navtitle), what is the meaning of a service-to-service application?

Couldn't find any concrete source on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=service-to-service%20application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is basically that of a trusted application calling a trusted application (the client is another service).  Retrieving a service to service token is usually more simple, and quicker, than retrieving a token for a client because the service is already trusted (running in a controlled environment). Here is some info on AD OAuth for svs to svs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service

In reference to bots specifically, it isn't always necessary to retrieve a token to call the bot, because the secret itself can be used in a service-to-service call (since the code in the service isn't exposed to any end users).

Comment: This definition seems to make sense to me too